# What is the use of 'WHERE TRUE' in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working on my colleague's old project and I found on her code `WHERE TRUE AND ID='1' AND STAT='1'`. 
I've tried to removed `TRUE AND` so the query become `WHERE ID='1' AND STAT='1'` and get the same result.

I know we can use `TRUE`as boolean to search 'where something is true' such as `WHERE FLAG = TRUE` and [this MySQL documentation state that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html)

> The constants TRUE and FALSE evaluate to 1 and 0, respectively. The constant names can be written in any lettercase.

I also tried `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE TRUE` but it's just the same as `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE`

what is the purpose of `TRUE` in her query?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It has no specific functional purpose. Your colleague may have included it if they were adhering to a specific style guide that recommends that all SELECT queries have explicit WHERE clauses. If an explicit WHERE clause is not provided, the default is to select all rows. Adding a WHERE clause that is always true will have the same effect.

Another way this query could have come about is if it was generated by a code generation tool that always had to write in a WHERE clause due to the way it was written.

for example:

```
myQuery = "SELECT X FROM Y WHERE " + ConditionMet(data)?" AccountID = '" + AcctId + "'" : "1=1";
```

This means that if ConditionMet(data) is true, then only return rows where AccountID matches the AcctId you are passing in. If it is false, then return all rows.

Adding a "dummy" 1=1 makes the code generator simpler to write. More generally, `1=1` is as legitimate a boolean clause as any other, and can be "dropped" into a conditional expression without having to special-case the query to omit the `WHERE` clause.

Similarly, adding a WHERE clause that is always false (e.g. "WHERE 1=0") will result in zero rows being returned.

Do note that the example code here is vulnerable to SQL Injection, so it should not be used in cases where you are dealing with AccountID's that you did not produce yourself. There are multiple ways to secure it that are beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you're writing your SQLString on runtime, and you might add different "where" clausules but you don't know which of all of them will be the first, it makes it easy as all of them may start with "AND ....."

Example:

```
SQLString:='SELECT * FROM YOUTABLE WHERE TRUE'

If condition1 THEN SQLString:=SQLString+' AND Whatever=whatever';
If condition2 THEN SQLString:=SQLString+' AND Whatever=whatever';
If condition3 THEN SQLString:=SQLString+' AND Whatever=whatever';
If condition4 THEN SQLString:=SQLString+' AND Whatever=whatever';
```

otherwhise, you should add the WHERE clause not on the first SQLString:= but on the first condition that happens to be true, which you don't know will it be a priori

Answer (score 1):

it is not as much relevant but if find important where adding dynamic conditions,for example in php.

```
  $condition_stmt="";
    if ($start_date !="" && $end_date!="")
    {
        $condition_stmt="and nos.status_date between '".$start_date."' and '".$end_date."'";
    }
    else if ($start_date!="")
    {
        $condition_stmt="and nos.status_date >='".$start_date."'";
    }
    else 
    {
        $condition_stmt="and nos.status_date <='".$end_date."'";
    }
```

$sql="select * from table where true ".$condition_stmt=.";

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that it also helps with productivity by facilitating commenting out lines when testing queries.

For example, in

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE col1 = 'foo'
AND col2 = 'bar'
```

it's not possible to easily remove the `col1 = 'foo'` condition.

In contrast, if we use

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE TRUE
AND col1 = 'foo'
AND col2 = 'bar'
```

the `AND col1 = 'foo'` can be instantaneously commented out and the query will still work.